# Can IDA generate C code for ASM assembly without the binary?

Tags: ida, assembly, c, decompile, binary

Lets say I have this picture of some assembly:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/nlgdsRC.png]

Now I know how to manual tranform this assembly into C code because it is small but is it possible for IDA to convert this into C code? Ideally I would write parts of the assembly or the entire thing and IDA would try to generate the C code for it. I don't have the binary, just pictures of various small programs (all linux x86). Also don't have any code segments etc (only the picture to guide me).

Right now I only know how to generate C code if I have the compiled binary.

I am using IDA Pro + Decompiler.

Comment: No. Ida doesn't work from text without binary.AFAIK the only solution you have is to recompile your assembly code, create binary and load it into IDA.

Comment: @ws Ah but that might be silly given the short length of the programs (would take some time to type up the assembly and so on). Thanks!